# MACROS in gamemaker function throwing error

Tags: function, macros, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

This Code
`var within_rangex = is_within(x,o_player.x,PLAYER_REACH);`

throwing the error

> Got ';' (;) expected ','

I Have No Idea Why, when using magic numbers there is no error thrown.

EDIT:
The Script In Which PLAYER_REACH Is Defined.

```
// This Script Contains Code To Create enums And macros

function enums(){
    enum states{
        normal,
        jumping
    }
    
    #macro TILE_REFRESH_RATE    10; // How Often Will A Tile Update Accure
    #macro PLAYER_REACH         64; // How Far Can The Player Reach
}
```

Comment: You need to show us how/where `PLAYER_REACH` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I Found It. The Simi-colons Can't Be Used In MACROS. Always Forget This.

Here Is The Fixed Code.

```
// This Script Contains Code To Create enums And macros

function enums(){
    enum states{
        normal,
        jumping
    }
    
    #macro TILE_REFRESH_RATE    10; // How Often Will A Tile Update Accure
    #macro PLAYER_REACH         64; // How Far Can The Player Reach
}
```